# displaying multiple pandas function created on python in the same csv file

Tags: python, pandas

How can i display multiple pandas function created on python in the same csv file

So I have multiple data tables saved as pandas dataframes, and I want to output all of them into the same CSV for ease of access. However, I am not really sure the best way to go about this, as I want to maintain each dataframes inherent structure (ie columns and index), so I can combine them all into 1 single dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks alot for the comment Kingotto, I used to first option added the this code and it was able to help me arrange my functions horizontally and exported the file to csv like this:

```
frames = pd.concat([file_1, file_2, file_3], axis = 1)
```

## save the dataframe

```
frames.to_csv('Combined.csv', index = False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 choices:

1. Either you combine them first (`pd.concat()`) with all the advantages and limitations of that appraoch, then you cann call `.to_csv` and it will print 1 file. If they are structurally the same, this is great because you will be able to read the file again.
2. Or, you call `.to_csv()` multiple times, and save the output in a "buffer", which you can then write (see [here](https://pythontic.com/pandas/serialization/to_csv)). Probably the only way if your DataFrames are very different from a structural perspective, but a mess to read them later.

Is .json output an option for what you want to do?

Comment: .json is not an option

Comment: The length (vertical axis) of the file and the headers are identical. but the content are different. I intend merging them on the same file.  for example

Comment: I like the choice 1.. because both files are structurally the same

Can you help me with the code using (pd.concat()) to combine this function horizontally in 1 csv sheet